# Calculate value relative to another value

Tags: python, math

Im trying to control a return value, relative to an input value.

So fx. iv'e got a input value. lets call it `A`.
This Value i know will be between 0 and 500.
Then i want to calculate and output a value (`B`) between 0 and 360, but relative to what `A` is..

So fx if i `A = 500`, then `B == 360`... or if `A = 250` then `B == 180` and so on...

How would i programmaticly, well really its a math question i guess?

Kinda hard to explain, so hope it makes sense

Comment: Any specific relation between `A` and `B`?

Comment: Not really, other that max and min. thats why @thefourheye's answer is very nice, i can just introduce variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the percentage of `A` and then use that percentage on `B`, like this

```
B = (A/500.0) * 360
```

For example,

```
def get_b(a):
    return (a/500.0) * 360

print get_b(500)
print get_b(250)
print get_b(125)
```

**Output**

```
360.0
180.0
90.0
```

Answer (score 0):

> How would i programmaticly, well really its a math question i guess?

You have already received an answer, but the only part I would differ from @thefourtheye is the explanation. Simply use the unitary method in the following manner

**Explanation**

```
A          B
-------------
500  -->  360
  1  -->  360.500
  A --->  360/500*A
        = 0.72 * A
```

**Implementation**

```
def get_b(a):
    return 0.72 * A
```